# XamlC Argument cannot be null

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using the new XamlC feature.
Placing the: [XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] attribute
works fine on some views, but on one specific view I get this error:

Replacing "MyViewName".InitializeComponent ()... failed.
"MyViewName".xaml: error : Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Why?

Comment: `XamlC` is a beta feature, and this is not the proper channel to report bugs. This won't be helpful to anyone in a few weeks time. The issue is known and is dressed, and a solution will come in a later release with XamlC enabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question, it's a bug report

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix, the proper answer would be: "It is a bug, we are working on it". Your answer assumes I know it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the Beta version of Xamarin.Forms.
They are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've already reported it ([here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29300)) and found a workaround for it:

You should specify the primitive types:

```
  <!--Working-->
  <local:DummyView >
    <local:DummyView.Text>
      <x:String>
        test
      </x:String>
    </local:DummyView.Text>
    <local:DummyView.NumOfRepeat>
      <x:Int32>
        4
      </x:Int32>
    </local:DummyView.NumOfRepeat>
  </local:DummyView>
```